# Disbelief at gullibility

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is the name for a feeling (name of facial expression much welcome too) you'd experience, when facing someone apparently believing an obvious lie or scam?

> "So, imagine this, the guy who came to install Internet, he said for twenty bucks he can add Google to my package, so that I can search the web for free. And for another ten bucks he installed Wikipedia!"
>
> I checked his screen. Indeed, there were two shortcuts on the desktop, one opening the browser on Google.com, and the other on Wikipedia.org.
>
> "Did you really pay thirty bucks for two shortcuts on your desktop?"

If I want to replace speech in the last sentence with just a description of what appears on that person's face, how would you phrase that?

Comment: I'd have a look of _incredulity_ on my face, although one can look incredulously at many things, not just profound gullibility.

Comment: This would be a good discussion for http://writers.stackexchange.com/   In terms of your question, are you more interested in a simile or a single word? Which would enhance the passage most for you?

Comment: @tylerharms: They tend to send people with single word requests back here ;) It doesn't have to be a single word - if a concise expression conveys that better, it's perfectly okay.

Comment: I agree with SF; sometimes we are too quick to send someone to Writers.SE. I just read their [FAQ](http://writers.stackexchange.com/faq), and fail to see how this would be a good fit for that forum.

Comment: @SF: Agreed. Note the use of "would be" in the above comment to suggest that you might also find some usefulness, as would the community, in asking it there. To take a stab at answering it, though, I, personally, would look at the bookmarked pages and sigh a sigh of regret for human frailty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was the same as @J.R.'s. I would be [incredulous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incredulous):

> (of a person or their manner) unwilling or unable to believe something:

I might also stare in [disbelief](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disbelief), look [dumbfounded](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dumbfound), or appear [blutterbunged](http://books.google.com/books?id=h9zXAAAAMAAJ&q=blutterbunged) with amazement. I would then [roll my eyes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/roll+one%27s+eyes) to convey my disapproval.

> **roll one's eyes**, to turn one's eyes around in different directions or in a circle, **especially as an expression of disbelief, annoyance, or impatience**: *He rolled his eyes when he heard the stupid joke.*

<sup><sub>*Blutterbunged* sounds like more of a perfect fit than it actually is.</sub></sup>

Comment: All the words you offered work here. However, I have a feeling the OP has a concept that more profound.

Comment: @Kris _Profound_ incredulity, _profound_ disbelief, etc. might be the ticket then ;)

Comment: :) No. I meant the concept was profound not the emotion!

Comment: They are pretty nice but I guess I meant something more condescending. It's not just being surprised, it's a very disappointed/disapproving kind of surprise.

Comment: @SF. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the scenario, this would work for me:

***"Wide-eyed, dropped-jaw, complete and utter disbelief"***